# arrange view to show 3 x 3 grid of nodes

Tags: views, nodes, entities, blocks, theming

How would i get Drupal to show a 3x3 grid of nodes of a certain content type.

I've tried using both Format:Grid and Format:Table. Also I used Show: Fields and Show: Teasers but it doesn't work out the way I want.

I am wondering if it's best to use 2 separate blocks of 3 nodes with an offset for the second block so that the 1st block shows nodes 1,2,3 and the 2nd block shows 4,5,6.

This is all related to 1 single content type with fields which include. 1 Image, and 1 URL.

Comment: You can show your own view mode (like teaser, but a display format you have defined yourself) in Views, so you could try using Drupal's built-in capabilities or the Display Suite module to get a view mode that shows the nodes the way you like, and then use a grid or table to display that view mode.

Comment: I had a look at display suite but that looks really complicated. I was hoping there might just be something to add to the CSS to make it work

Comment: You don't need Display Suite; you can use view modes without Display Suite and handle the display with a theme template.  You could also probably do it just in CSS but pure CSS questions are better asked on Stack Overflow than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using format and pager settings this should be possible.

**Add Format type of Grid**

[image: Format - Grid]

**Set the number of columns under the Format settings to "3"**

[image: Number of columns - 3]

**Set page to only show 9 items**

[image: Page - Display specific number - 9]

Set the filter to only show nodes of a specific content type: 
[image: Filter - Content Type]

Now all you need to do is set the view fields, filter, sort, and other options to your liking.  Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked perfectly.